# How a simple navigation app works?

Tags: iphone, ios

I created a simple navigation app with the help of http://gigaom.com/apple/iphone-dev-sessions-create-a-navigation-based-application/. But i have little confusion in a line which i have given below.

```
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
```

in

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];       
}
```

in my Delegate.h i have.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Here we can see that navigationController points to UINavigationController. My whole confusion is in the line below.

```
[navigationController view]
```

How this line works? perhaps it point to my RootViewController.xib and if it is yes then how it be?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the when you create a navigation controller, it is simply a means of controller a stack of views. In order to actually add a view to the window using `addSubview:(UIView *)`, you must retrieve the view of the navigation controller using `[navigationController view]`, which gets the view for the given navigation controller, allowing you to set it in the app's main window. I hope that makes sense. You should consider reading some introductions to objective-c.

Comment: OK but RootViewController.h has also a RootViewController.xib file. but in our whole program we are not using the xib file of RootViewController then what is the use of putting RootViewController.xib in the iPhone project if it has no use?

Comment: If you are not linking to it anywhere else, then you do not need it. In my last project, I deleted RootViewController right away because I wanted to start with my own custom controllers.

Answer (score 1):

A navigation controller manages a self-contained view hierarchy (known as a navigation interface) whose contents are composed partly of views managed directly by the navigation controller and partly of views managed by custom view controllers you provide. Each custom view controller manages a distinct view hierarchy but a navigation controller coordinates the navigation between different view hierarchies.

When an application is launched the function

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
```

is called. Inside this function you add a subview of the application window. It may be your viewController,tabBarController or navigationController (depend on the type of application you want to make). when

```
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
```

is compiled. It adds the view attached to the navigation controller which is rootViewController in navigation based application iphone.

If you want in detail how navigation controller works. check this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

**Q: How this line works?**
**A:**  It'll dispatch your navigationController's view, `[navigationController view]` equeals `navigationController.view`.
If you initiate your NavigationController with nib file, it'll be clear.
Here I create a file: `CustomNavigationController.xib`, and my navigationController will load it as its view:
  [image]
You can see navigationController's view right, and it contains a navigationBar at top.
Navigation Controller works with `pushViewController`, `popViewController`, etc, it loads & unloads viewController's view at gray area in picture.

**Q: perhaps it point to my RootViewController.xib and if it is yes then how it be?**
**A:** I'm not sure your `RootViewController.xib` is what. Maybe it is your main view controller's.
`[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];` is just add your navigationController's view to main window as a subview.
If your app is based on Navigation Controller, you can set it as the root view controller for window(like `self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;` at `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method).
Generally speaking, one app has one window, but lots views. View Controllers can load x/nib file as its view. Maybe you need to read more about MVC(Model-View-Controller). :)